# Getting "Value cannot be null" exception with CheckBoxListFor Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pulling a list of values from a reference table in the Database and using CheckBoxListFor to display them in my MVC4 View. Now, everything works fine with the initial load, validation and with posting the selected values back to the controller. My problem only happens if, for some reason, my controller triggers a validation error and returns to the View that originated the post in the first place.

My ViewModel:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public ICollection<GoodsType> GoodsType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GoodsType> SelectedGoodsType { get; set; }
    public PostedGoodsType PostedGoodsType { get; set; }

    public class PostedGoodsType
    {
        public string[] GoodsTypeIDs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<ul id="typeOfGoodsCheckBoxList" class="formList botDots twinCols clearfix">
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedGoodsType.GoodsTypeIDs,
                                   model => model.GoodsType,
                                   entity => entity.GoodsTypeID,
                                   entity => entity.GoodsTypeDesc,
                                   model => model.SelectedGoodsType)
</ul>
```

My Controller:

```
// This Action is loaded on the first request
public ActionResult DeclareDetails(int? declarationID = null)
{
    return View(viewModel);
}

// This action is called on the submit
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SubmitDeclareDetails(DetailsViewModel viewModel)
{
    var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    // Validate ViewModel
    var command = Mapper.Map<Declaration, CreateOrUpdateDeclarationCommand>(viewModel.Declaration);
    errors = _commandBus.Validate(command).ToList();
    // Add the custom errors to the modelstate
    ModelState.AddModelErrors(errors);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = _commandBus.Submit(command);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("DeclareVehicle", viewModel);
        }
    }
    // If something went wrong, go back to the page and display the errors
    return View("DeclareDetails", viewModel);
}
```

And when I get a validation error and my ModelState.IsValid is false, I want to return to the initial view, passing the ViewModel but I get this error:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error:

```
Line 296:                    </legend>
Line 297:                    <ul id="typeOfGoodsCheckBoxList" class="formList botDots     twinCols clearfix">
Line 298:                        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedGoodsType.GoodsTypeIDs,
Line 299:                                              model => model.GoodsType,
Line 300:                                              entity => entity.GoodsTypeID,
```

I tried initializing the objects when creating the ViewModel but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: where is the rest of the CheckBoxListFor? Post it please

Comment: and which Actions returns the view where the CheckBoxListFor is?

Comment: What you mean the rest? I'm using an extension, like described in here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-a-missing-MVC-extension
The action that returns the CheckBoxListFor is "DeclareDetails".

Comment: Your CheckBoxListFor has a `(` and a `)`, I only see the beggining and I dont see the end of it

Comment: Lines 297 and onward contain the same code as I posted a bit up on the section labeled as "My View:". That's the code. The part where you see the line numbers is the error I get and that's all that's shown in the error page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not the correct format: (Type, Enum_with_values, option-label, object-attributes)

Comment: You have checked to see that viewModel has bound back your original checkbox list... if it didn't model bind your entire checkbox list back on post then you'd get that error I believe

Comment: Thanks Rikon, that was the problem indeed. I was relying on the extension to initialize my objects for me but I needed to initialize all the objects that I'm using in the CheckBoxListFor otherwise they won't be bound to the model and will be null when they are posted back. I'll post the solution below. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rikon's comment on the OP, I've managed to figure out the problem. My problem was that I have 3 different entities (reference tables) in the same View that use CheckBoxListFor and 2 of them are mutually exclusive.

Therefore, whenever I post back, one of those 3 entities was always null, so when I posted it back, that entity was null and threw the above exception.

The solution was to simply initialize the objects used in the CheckBoxListFor even if I don't use them. This way, they'll always be bound to the model and can be passed back and forth.

```
public SelfDeclareOperatorDetailsViewModel()
{
    GoodsType = new List<GoodsType>();
    SelectedGoodsType = new List<GoodsType>();
    PostedGoodsType = new PostedGoodsType { GoodsTypeIDs = new string[0] };
}
```

Thanks again everyone!